# Trying to pass a value in client side textbox to a server side method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to pass a value at client side text box which is generated dynamically, to a server side method.How to achieve it,any idea would be appreciated.
.aspx

```
 $("#pdfFormInsideTblRight").append("<table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th class='text-center'>TDC No.</th>" +
                        "<th><input id='Tdc_No' type='text' value='7y'/></th></tr></thead>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-center'>Revision</td>" +
                        "<td><label id='Revision' value ='0'>0</label></td></tr>" +
                        "<tr><td class='text-center'>Date</td>" +
                        "<td><label id='Revision_Date'></label></td></tr></table>");
```

c#

```
 protected void Export_to_PDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = GetData("SELECT * FROM tdc_product1 where TDC_NO = " + __ ;
    }
```

I want the value at `<input id='Tdc_No' type='text' value='7y'/>`
in Export_to_PDF method at this condition `where TDC_NO = " + __ ;`at underline position.

Comment: get using Tdc_No.Text

Comment: You should pass it with an `ajax` request...

Comment: Be wary of sql injection, use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to accomplish this:

- with an [asp:TextBox control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)
- adding a button and on server side (if you're using web forms)

  ```
  if (IsPostBack) {
      var value = Request.QUesystring["buttonName"];
      [...]
  }
  ```

Comment: in my case i am generating the input control dynamically .so without using asp:TextBox control can't i get value in server side method.